# Flink stream synchronization between 2 joined topics

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a use case where i want to join 2 topics lets say topicA and topicB on one key. And i want if topicA data comes out ofnsync or with some delay the processing just waits for it to arrive. Once the message is topicA arrives than only it processes that message on topicB. Similar to what we can achieve by left join KTables in kafka.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing above is a "stateful join". Typically this is handled with a custom `RichCoFlatMapFunction` (or `KeyedCoProcessFunction`, if you need things like timers to expire unjoined record). As an example, see the [EnrichmentFunction](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/release-1.11/rides-and-fares/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/ridesandfares/RidesAndFaresSolution.java) in the https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/release-1.11/rides-and-fares tutorial.